# Search for folders created after date X and copy them

Tags: powershell, copy, directory, subdirectory, datecreated

I need to go through a large folder (let's call it D:\Files ) which contains about 50.000 folders and about 1 million files, and copy all folders that were created (not modified) after August 31th 2012, including everything in their subfolders (including second/third/fourth level deep subfolders etc.) and files (also files in subfolders, no matter when they got changed) in those folders, for them no matter when they were created, as long as they're in a "higher up" folder that go created after August, to another drive (Call it E:\Space) - still keeping the original folder structure, so a file which was before in D:\Files\Folder1\Subfolder3\hello.txt then should be in E:\Space\Folder1\Subfolder3\hello.txt

Background is, some folders got created in the structure after August, but the files in them do have an older modified date and I need to include everything in the search process that was added to D:\Files after 31st August 2012, so I can't figure out which files were recently added, and which were in there already before August, and I need to search for the folder creation date.

So, if the folder D:\Files\Folder1 got created in September, then files and folders in it - be it one, two, three, four etc. levels deep, no matter when it got changed/modified, should be moved to E:\Space with the powershell.

I've tried in the past two days to get through, but so far failed miserably.

I know this probably isn't easy with Powershell as it requires several steps, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Comment: And.... what have you tried??

Comment: I'm not sure how this question is related to programming languages. Doesn't look like a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$srcRoot = "D:\Files"
$dstRoot = "D:\Space"

$ct = Get-Date "2012-09-01"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse $srcRoot | ? {
  $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -ge $ct
} | sort FullName | % {
  $name = $_.FullName
  if ($top -eq $null) {
    $top = $name
  } elseif ( $name.substring(0, [math]::Min($top.Length, $name.Length)) -ne $top ) {
    $top = $name
    $dst = $_ -replace [regex]::Escape($srcRoot), $dstRoot
    Copy-Item $name $dst -Recurse -Force
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using robocopy.exeto solve the task.

If youre looking for a ps Solution have a Look on the scriptinggames 2013 Event 1 submissions

Comment: `robocopy` does not meet his requirements. He wants to copy matching folders with their entire content, whereas `robocopy` works on a per-file basis.